# How do I set the selected item in a comboBox to match my string using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a string "test1" and my comboBox contains `test1`, `test2`, and `test3`. How do I set the selected item to "test1"? That is, how do I match my string to one of the comboBox items?

I was thinking of the line below, but this doesn't work.

```
comboBox1.SelectedText = "test1";
```

Comment: how doesn't it work? What happens when this line of code runs?

Comment: @KateGregory it just concatenates the "test1" string to the existing text

Comment: If u have a way to know the item value you can use: comboBox1.SelectedValue = Value_of_your_string;

Comment: `SelectedText` changes the "Selected" text to test1. if there is no "Selection" (marked text) made, text will be inserted in caret's position.

Answer (score 332):

This should do the trick:

```
Combox1.SelectedIndex = Combox1.FindStringExact("test1")
```

Comment: Seems a better answer to me because you have a return value you can save temporary in a variable and use it to test wether you have found the value you were looking for.

Comment: what if there are more than one "test1" value in combox1

Comment: @thoitbk - According to the MSDN at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, the method `FindStringExact()` **"Finds the first item in the combo box that matches the specified string."**

Answer (score 222):

Have you tried the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) property? It works for me.

```
ComboBox1.Text = "test1";
```

The SelectedText property is for the selected portion of the editable text in the textbox part of the combo box.

Comment: Surely that just sets the text in the editable area of the ComboBox rather than selecting the relevant item from the list?  If the list items collection contains objects rather than just strings, then I doubt this would select the appropriate ListItem object, rather it would just set the Text property on the ComboBox?

Comment: It does set the SelectedValue property of the control

Comment: Nice.  Works beautifully for font size, weight, and family pulldowns.  No casts or conversions between classes.  Soooo much easier!

Comment: Just in case : This parameter must be set only after populating the combobox.

Comment: there is no .Text in silverlight.

Comment: It does not work when ComboBox .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

Comment: I was looking for how to set a combobox, and I thought it would be some convoluted process but this does the trick!

Comment: My combobox dropdownstyle is DropDownList and .Text = "some text" does not work. This solution worked fine for me: Combox1.SelectedIndex = Combox1.FindStringExact("test1")

Comment: This solution seems to work for me. Thanks! For good measure I also put in SelectedItem to be the same as Text.

Answer (score 53):

Assuming that your combobox isn't databound you would need to find the object's index in the "items" collection on your form and then set the "selectedindex" property to the appropriate index.

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf("test1");
```

Keep in mind that the IndexOf function may throw an argumentexception if the item isn't found.

Comment: Remember its SelectedINDEX not SelectedITEM...And the compiler won't complain, just fail to set the combobox value

Comment: Don't you love logical errors that don't throw any exception, they just don't work...

Comment: this is selecting the item, but not calling the onChange event on the combobox

Comment: `IndexOf` will only throw an exception if you pass it `null`.  Merely not finding the item will cause it to return -1 (which conveniently is a valid value for `SelectedIndex`)

Answer (score 44):

If the items in your ComboBox are strings, you can try:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = "test1";
```

Comment: No it is not:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx

Comment: Saved the day! The selected item must match the type - that was it for me! I was scratching my head why the selected item was not set even the item was clearly there - turned out to be a type mismatch!

Comment: For completeness, useful to have the description from the above link, especially since this answer performs the matching check suggested by other answers including the preferred one from @norbertB:  **When you set the SelectedItem property to an object, the ComboBox attempts to make that object the currently selected one in the list.** _If the object is found in the list_, **it is displayed in the edit portion of the ComboBox and the SelectedIndex property is set to the corresponding index. If the object does not exist in the list, the SelectedIndex property is left at its current value.**

Answer (score 18):

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex= ComboBox1.FindString("Matching String");
```

Try this in windows Form.

Answer (score 14):

For me this worked only:

```
foreach (ComboBoxItem cbi in someComboBox.Items)
{
    if (cbi.Content as String == "sometextIntheComboBox")
    {
        someComboBox.SelectedItem = cbi;
        break;
    }
}
```

MOD: and if You have your own objects as items set up in the combobox, then substitute the ComboBoxItem with one of them like:

```
foreach (Debitor d in debitorCombo.Items)
{
    if (d.Name == "Chuck Norris")
    {
        debitorCombo.SelectedItem = d;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but you need to be careful that the items in your ComboBox are actually ComboBoxItems as it's possible to put other items in there too.

Comment: This worked great in WinRT 8.1.  I actually wrapped the top foreach in an extension method like dave wrote in his SelectItemByValue() solution, and it was really the perfect solution.

Answer (score 10):

SelectedText is to get or set the actual text in the string editor for the selected item in the combobox as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx) .  This goes uneditable if you set:

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Use:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = "test1";
```

or:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf("test1");
```

Comment: comboBox1.Items.IndexOf... risks a NullReferenceException if Items is empty.

Comment: @Gary: No it doesn't, `Items` will always be an non-null collection, even if there are no items in the collection (`Items.Count == 0`)

Answer (score 10):

I've used an extension method:

```
public static void SelectItemByValue(this ComboBox cbo, string value)
{
    for(int i=0; i < cbo.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var prop = cbo.Items[i].GetType().GetProperty(cbo.ValueMember);
        if (prop!=null && prop.GetValue(cbo.Items[i], null).ToString() == value)
        {
             cbo.SelectedIndex = i;
             break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Then just consume the method:

```
ddl.SelectItemByValue(value);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem.Text = "test1";
```

Answer (score 5):

Supposing test1, test2, test3 belong to comboBox1 collection following statement will work.

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: This does not always work... See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839444/invalidargument-value-of-0-is-not-valid-for-selectedindex-parameter-name-s

Answer (score 5):

I've filled my ComboBox with een DataTable filled from a database. Then I've set the DisplayMember and the ValueMember. And I use this code to set the selected item.

```
foreach (DataRowView Row in ComboBox1.Items)
{
    if (Row["ColumnName"].ToString() == "Value") ComboBox1.SelectedItem = Row;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution is based on [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network) with some modifications I made.

- It finds exact or **PART** of string and sets it.

  ```
  private int lastMatch = 0;
  private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Set our intial index variable to -1.
      int x = 0;
      string match = textBoxSearch.Text;
      // If the search string is empty set to begining of textBox
      if (textBoxSearch.Text.Length != 0)
      {
          bool found = true;
          while (found)
          {
              if (comboBoxSelect.Items.Count == x)
              {
                  comboBoxSelect.SelectedIndex = lastMatch;
                  found = false;
              }
              else
              {
                  comboBoxSelect.SelectedIndex = x;
                  match = comboBoxSelect.SelectedValue.ToString();
                  if (match.Contains(textBoxSearch.Text))
                  {
                      lastMatch = x;
                      found = false;
                  }
                  x++;
              }
          }
      }
      else
          comboBoxSelect.SelectedIndex = 0;
  }
  ```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

- Enumerate ListItems in combobox
- Get equal ones listindex set combobox
- Set listindex to the found one.

But if I see such a code as a code reviewer, I would recommend to reconsider all the method algorithm.

Comment: Why have you provided it as an answer then?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have that property in the ComboBox. You have SelectedItem or SelectedIndex. If you have the objects you used to fill the combo box then you can use SelectedItem.

If not you can get the collection of items (property Items) and iterate that until you get the value you want and use that with the other properties.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
_cmbTemplates.SelectedText = "test1"
```

or maybe

```
_cmbTemplates.SelectedItem= _cmbTemplates.Items.Equals("test1");
```

Comment: with this code, you assign a bool to the SelectedItem property ... won't work imho.

Answer (score 2):

I used **KeyValuePair**  for ComboBox data bind and I wanted to find item by **value** so this worked in my case:

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = comboBox.Items.Cast<KeyValuePair<string,string>>().First(item=> item.Value == "value to match");
```

Answer (score 2):

Find mySecondObject (of type MyObject) in combobox (containing a list of MyObjects) and select the item:

```
foreach (MyObject item in comboBox.Items)
{
   if (item.NameOrID == mySecondObject.NameOrID)
    {
        comboBox.SelectedItem = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  ListItem li = DropDownList.Items.FindByValue("13001");
  DropDownList.SelectedIndex = ddlCostCenter.Items.IndexOf(li);
```

For your case you can use

```
DropDownList.Items.FindByText("Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
combo.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
```

Comment: This also risks an exception if "1" is not found.

Answer (score 1):

All methods, tricks, and lines of code setting ComboBox item will not work until the ComboBox has a parent.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Function which will return the Index of the Value

```
        public static int SelectByValue(ComboBox comboBox, string value)
        {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= comboBox.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                DataRowView cb;
                cb = (DataRowView)comboBox.Items[i];
                if (cb.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString() == value)// Change the 0 index if your want to Select by Text as 1 Index
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me.....

```
comboBox.DataSource.To<DataTable>().Select(" valueMember = '" + valueToBeSelected + "'")[0]["DislplayMember"];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what the OP asked but could it be that they don't know?  There are already several answers here so even though this is lengthy I thought it could be useful to the community.

Using an enum to fill a combo box allows for easy use of the SelectedItem method to programmatically select items in the combobox as well as loading and reading from the combobox.

```
public enum Tests
    {
        Test1,
        Test2,
        Test3,
        None
    }

// Fill up combobox with all the items in the Tests enum
    foreach (var test in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Tests)))
    {
        cmbTests.Items.Add(test);
    }

    // Select combobox item programmatically
    cmbTests.SelectedItem = Tests.None.ToString();
```

If you double click the combo box you can handle the selected index changed event:

```
private void cmbTests_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Enum.TryParse(cmbTests.Text, out Tests theTest))
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Unable to convert {cmbTests.Text} to a valid member of the Tests enum");
        return;
    }

    switch (theTest)
    {
        case Tests.Test1:
            MessageBox.Show("Running Test 1");
            break;

        case Tests.Test2:
            MessageBox.Show("Running Test 2");
            break;

        case Tests.Test3:
            MessageBox.Show("Running Test 3");
            break;

        case Tests.None:

            // Do nothing

            break;

        default:
            MessageBox.Show($"No support for test {theTest}.  Please add");
            return;
    }
}
```

You can then run tests from a button click handler event:

```
 private void btnRunTest1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbTests.SelectedItem = Tests.Test1.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are binding Datasource via Dataset, then you should use "SelectedValue"

```
cmbCategoryList.SelectedValue = (int)dsLookUp.Tables[0].Select("WHERE PRODUCTCATEGORYID = 1")[0]["ID"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can say `comboBox1.Text = comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();`

Answer (score -2):

Please try this way, it works for me:

```
Combobox1.items[Combobox1.selectedIndex] = "replaced text";
```

Comment: You should check that selectedIndex is not -1 first, or more precisely that it is >= 0 and < .items.length.

Answer (score -3):

It should work

```
Yourcomboboxname.setselecteditem("yourstring");
```

And if you want to set database string use this

```
Comboboxname.setselecteditem(ps.get string("databasestring"));
```