# ComboBox filling

Tags: c#, combobox, fill

I have a problem filling my `ComboxBox`. Here´s my code:

```
string[] test = { "Ausgaben", "Eingaben" };
foreach (string r in test)
{
   cbEinAus.Items.Add(r);
}
```

The values from the string array are in the `ComboBox`, but the selected item is a empty string. 
I want one of this two string from the array to be my selected item.

I already tried with the `SelectedItem` property, but that doesn´t work.

Maybe its a simple solution... Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
cbEinAus.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

You can replace the `0` with the zero based index of whichever item you want to select.

Comment: Thanks guy, this was the solution... great

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cbEinAus.Items[vbEinAus.SelectedIndex]
```

instead of SelectedItem.  usually works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the SelectedItem as `cbEinAus.Items[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) property.

```
cbEinAus.Text = test[0];
```

More examples can be found at [How do I set the selected item in a comboBox to match my string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450059/c-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-in-a-combobox-to-match-my-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
cbEinAus.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

replace item to index