# InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I am getting the above error when i am trying this code. I tried giving [**just my code**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx) but no use. (It was default)

[**Here is my XML file**](http://ideone.com/OnpgJ)

The error is in `cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
        cmbProduct --> combobox
        cmbBrand   --> combobox
```

**Global**

```
        DataSet dsUpdate = new DataSet();
```

**Form_load**

```
        dsUpdate.ReadXml(@"...\..\stock.xml");
        cmbProduct.DataSource = dsUpdate.Tables[0]
            .DefaultView.ToTable(true, "productname");//.DefaultView;
        cmbProduct.DisplayMember = "productname";
        cmbProduct.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

**cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged**

```
        cmbBrand.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow Row in dsUpdate.Tables[0].Select("productname='" + cmbProduct.Text + "'"))
        {
            //cmbBrand.SelectedIndex = i;
            cmbBrand.Items.Add(Row["brandname"].ToString());
            //i++;
        } 
        cmbBrand.SelectedIndex = 0; /*ERROR*/
```

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does cmbBrand definitely have soem entries in it? Also can you confirm what object type cmbBrand is?

Comment: Yes it has entries. when i am not giving `cmbBrand.SelectedIndex = 0;` in `cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged` it is showing entries. but to make it not show null value at first, I added `cmbBrand.SelectedIndex = 0;`. and it is giving error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is:

when you start application, you do not have items in cmbBrand, but cmbProduct fires SelectedIndexChanged.

Try this:

remove SelectedIndexChanged event initialization from Form1.Designer.cs. Try to find following line:

```
this.cmbProduct.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

After that, when you populate DataSet with data from xml file, initialize SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
dsUpdate.ReadXml(@"...\..\stock.xml");
cmbProduct.DataSource = dsUpdate.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "productname");//.DefaultView;
cmbProduct.DisplayMember = "productname";
this.cmbProduct.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged);
cmbProduct.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: when i hover over the `cmbBrand.SelectedIndex = 0;` it is saying that it holds `-1` but as you can see in my xml file, it has values and also when i run without giving `cmbBrand.SelectedIndex = 0;`, my form showing values in cmbBrand, then ofcourse it doesnt hold `-1`. This what i cant understand.

Comment: yes this worked. I was thinking that form_load event will fire at first on beginning of a function these all days :). Thank you.

Comment: aaa this is not showing anything in cmbBrand on load of the form at first. Do you have any idea why so?

Comment: You need to specify what to show in cmbBrand. You just populate cmbProduct on loading

Comment: i need to change the value of `cmbProduct` manually to let the `cmbBrand` show the values. instead `cmbBrand` should show some values related to the selected values in `cmbProduct` on load only.

Comment: Hey no problem. i solved it. just added the same code in form load also :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this. Before setting combobox DataSource set its BindingContext

```
cmbProduct.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

Comment: This worked for me when creating a Dynamic ComboBox and trying to set a SelectedIndex. `var ComboBox1 = new ComboBox() { DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList(), BindingContext = this.BindingContext }; ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;`

Answer (score 2):

i had same error. i think this error have a some reasons.
so my error is related to "set `DataSource` in another thread is not working"

example

```
//Run in another thread
myComboBox.DataSource = myDataSource; //not set
```

fix with

```
myComboBox.Invoke(new Action(() => myComboBox.DataSource = myDataSource));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if you attempt to set the SelectedIndex while there is no valid datasource. If you're resetting the default to 0, and occasionally changing the datasource list, you may see this. You don't need to default to 0 if applying a new datasource, so simple check will avoid it happening:

if (comboBox.Datasource != null) comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue:

- use the **Form_Activated** event handler to control setting the indexes.
- For me, I had a series of dynamically generated ComboBoxes I added to a Form.
- I made a list of the ones where I wanted to use SetIndex=0, then iterated through them in this handler.
- I also had a boolean, firstFormActivation, when called the SetIndex the one time only..
- You can incidentally use this method for Focus() too, so first field in a Form gets focus when dynamically added.

Here is some code to illustrate the point:

```
    private readonly List<ComboBox> combosToSetIndexOn = new List<ComboBox>();
    private bool firstActivation = true;
    private Control firstWindowsControl = null;

    ...
    // Other code sets firstWindowsControl...

    private void DynamicForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (firstActivation)
        {
            firstActivation = false;
            bool fwcPresent = (firstWindowsControl != null);
            Console.WriteLine($"DynamicForm_Activated: firstWindowControl present: {fwcPresent}");
            if (fwcPresent)
            {
                firstWindowsControl.Focus();
            }

            if (combosToSetIndexOn.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (ComboBox c in combosToSetIndexOn)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"DynamicForm_Activated: processing: {c.Name}");
                    c.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following was causing my problem

```
myComboBox.DataSource = myBindingSource
myBindingSource.DataSource = items.ToList()  // error
```

The following worked

```
myComboBox.DataSource = null;
myBindingSource.DataSource = items.ToList();
MyComboBox.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```